# Creating list of tuples ( TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to generate a list of tuples e.g. `[('Client 0', 120),..,('Client 9', 45)]`, this is `totalitems` in the code. I'm using the below code however I am getting an error and I'm not really sure why.

```
N = 10 
value_range = np.arange(0, N, 1)
newitems = []       
for i in value_range:
    newvisits = ("Client %d" % i,) + random_tuple(length=6, values=(0, 15, 30, 45, 60))
    newitems.append(newvisits)

totalitems = []
i = 0 
for each_client in newitems:
    i += 1
    total = sum(each_client[1:])
    newtotal = ("Client %d" % i,) + tuple(total)
    totalitems.append(newtotals)
```

The error I get is:

```
newtotals = ("Client %d" % i,) + tuple(total)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I'm trying to find the total of each tuple in `totalitems`, obviously I need to ignore index[0].

Does anyone know where I am going wrong? Or any suggestions as to how to improve the code?

NB. `random_tuple` is quite self-explanatory, it returns a tuple with length 6 and each element is a random choice of the values.

Comment: In your second for loop, try something like

    `for i, each_client in enumerate(newitems):`

Comment: What is `random_tuple()`. Can you share what your data looks like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
newtotals = ("Client %d" % i,) + tuple(total)
```

`total` is a number. You can't convert it to a `tuple` like that; the `tuple()` class expects you to pass it a sequence. Try just building the tuple you want directly:

```
newtotals = ("Client %d" % i, total)
```

Comment: To add to kindall's answer, I think what OP meant by that line was

`newtotals = ("Client %d" % i,) + (total,)`

Comment: @kindall That's great, thank you! Also, I just noticed that this prints from `Client 1 to Client 10`, is there a way to change it so that it prints from `Client 0 to Client 9` so that it matches `newitems`?

Comment: I'd suggest using the `enumerate` function with your `for` loop. That way you don't need the separate statements to deal with `i`. So `for i, each_item in enumerate(newitems)`.